# how to add windows 7 ultimate enabled with bitlocker into windows 2003 domain?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2003

I would like to add a windows 7 ultimate system enabled with bitlocker on to a windows 2003 server domain controller and I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Can someone let me know the steps to be taken to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 2):

This should work the same as it would if you weren't using bitlocker:

- Go to my computer
- Click on System Properties
- Click Advanced System Properties
- Go to the Computer Name tab
- Click Change
- Select the Domain button and enter the domain name
- Enter the credentials required to add your computer to the domain